# How to accept Tuple of type Map<String,Object> in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-criteria

Currently Hibernate tuple accept `Map<String,String>` return type but i need return type of `Map<String,Object>` how to achieve this.

**Example:**

```
class User {
  long id;
  String imageUrl;
  Address address;

 String username;

 String password;

  String email;

}

class Address {
long id;
String name;
String Street code;
}
```

**My Criteria Query:**

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = builder.createTupleQuery();
    Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);
    cq.multiselect(
        root.get("imageUrl"),
        root.get("address"));
    cq.where(builder.equal(root.get("id"),3));
    Tuple tuple = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
    tuple.get(0);
// Error occurs for below code. (Stack over flow exception)
    tuple.get(1);
```

While getting `imageUrl` there is no error but when it tries to fetch `address` [Address type not string] attribute hibernate triggers stack over flow exception because it was trying to convert address to string.

Is there any other approach to achieve this.. ?

Comment: @gnanajeyam95 post your entire code on `User` and `Address` this issue is related to when tuple tries to get again Address and this User recursively.

Comment: @Oneguy i updated the complete code.

Comment: Are you sure this is whole code of `User` and `Address` and you didn't remove any method to make the code simpler? Are you suing Lombok?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki this is the actual code

Comment: Can you please add the `StackOverflowError` stack trace?

Comment: What does the Stack overflow exception have to do with the Map<String,Object> you are mentioning above?

Comment: @Dirk consider the response return type will be like this.

Comment: Try this `@Jsonignore  Address address;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `toString()` which the address to String.

Where the `toString()` method in Address class tries to print User object recursively.

That is the reason for `stackoverflow`.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue is with toString() which the address to String**